# Use Intellij or Eclipse to develop Groovy scripts for Hybris

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

Developing Groovy scripts within the HAC in Hybris doesn't have any code completion or as-you-type syntax checking, so I'd like to develop Groovy scripts for Hybris in Intellij (preferably) or Eclipse. Intellij supports Groovy projects, and Intellij is what I use for other Hybris development. I tried creating a Groovy project in Intellij (outside of my Hybris project - is that the problem?) and pasted the script I had started in HAC, but it seems like I'm missing some jar files, since all the import statements have **Cannot resolve symbol 'de'** errors.

> import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchService

, for example.

`flexibleSearchService = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService")` gives me a Cannot resolve symbol
'spring' error.

I wouldn't necessarily need to run the Groovy scripts in Intellij - although if that were possible, it would be very useful for debugging them. I'd just like to be able to catch all my syntax errors and use code completion in Intellij at least, then paste them into HAC to run.

Is this possible? What jar files do I need? Can I copy them from my local Hybris installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer the following questions:

1.*I tried creating a Groovy project in Intellij (outside of my Hybris project - is that the problem?)*

Yes, that is the problem. By creating **the groovy script in the same Hybris project** you have access to all hybris classes and **Intellij will suggest imports and code completion**.

2.*flexibleSearchService = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService") gives me a Cannot resolve symbol 'spring' error.*

Use **Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("flexibleSearchService")** instead

3.Is this possible?

Yes, it is possible and, as already implied in the question, this helps a lot by fixing syntax and also warnings that Intellij shows. Please see below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks dj_frunza - I think I'm in business - very helpful answer. Assuming if I start my local Hybris, I can actually run and debug my Groovy script in Intellij.

Comment: If I start my local Hybris I cannot run the Groovy Script from Intellij(only use copy  paste). I believe running impex and groovy should be possible with the Paid version of Hybris Intellij Plugin. If the groovy script calls a DAO or Service than you can debug inside those Java classes. Anyway for me it helps a lot to maintain the groovy script in Intellij and easily access and import everything from Hybris without worrying if the import does or does not work